# why am i getting a Error for text to speech?

Tags: python, speech

Let's get straight into it,I wrote a program earlier that functions properly but now I want it to speak.So I hoped on youtube and saw a video where this guy's program speaks in 4 lines of code.However when I tried, it didn't work.Here is the link for the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbX4MBzB_rg&list=PLqdqxXIQ9itPEvd4R0-Q6hdl9sPZYwVFA&index=11&t=189s

Here is my code:

```
import pyttsx3
friend = pyttsx3.init()
friend.say("Hello")
friend.runAndWait()
```

I get a TypeError:item 1 in *argtypes* passes a union by value, which is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly a solution to your problem here: https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/107

> I fixed it temporary installing 2.7 version
>   pip install pyttsx3==2.7

- olavomendes commented on Apr 19